# C# Faster Drawing Vector Graphics

Tags: c#-2.0

In my application I want to draw polygons using Windows Create Graphics method and later edit the polygon by allowing the user to select the points of the polygon and allowing to re-position them.

I use moue move event to get the new position of the point to get the new coordinates of the point being moved and use Paint event to re-draw the polygon. The application is working but when a point is moved the movement is not smooth. This is probably due to large numbe of mouse move and paint events firing while moving the point.

I dont know weather the mouse move or the paint event the performance hindrance.

Can anyone make a suggestion as to how to improve this?

Answer (score 0):

look at double buffering in c#. this can speed thing up greatly.

Comment: -1. Double buffering offers no speed increase, just prevents flickering. In fact, as an extra overhead to the drawing process, more CPU cycles are used to draw the same thing (albeit without the horrible flickering).

Answer (score 0):

From my Win32 expirience (not a .NET) the fastest vector graphic is Metafile. I dont know if the C# System.Drawing.Imaging.Metafile is as fast as Win32 one. Could be as fast as your video 2D hardware.